# How does Spacy's Matcher implement multithread

Tags: spacy

From the source code of Matcher, it seems that `pipe` is just calling the matching function one by one. Does it use multithreading or buffer content by batch_size at all?

```
def pipe(self, docs, batch_size=1000, n_threads=2):
    """Match a stream of documents, yielding them in turn.
    docs (iterable): A stream of documents.
    batch_size (int): Number of documents to accumulate into a working set.
    n_threads (int): The number of threads with which to work on the buffer
        in parallel, if the implementation supports multi-threading.
    YIELDS (Doc): Documents, in order.
    """
    for doc in docs:
        self(doc)
        yield doc
```

source: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher.pyx#L306